# How to separate line of access field?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have multi line field in access table!  I want to define first line as new field-1, second line as new field-2, and third line as new field-3 and forth line as new field-4.

Comment: Can you give example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: You may want to look at using a `Recordset` to loop through the table, and then `Split` to separate out the lines in the original field to new fields in the recordset. But without examples of the initial data and the desired output, nobody is going to be able to help you any further.....